# What would an optimally designed (maximising the capacitance) capacitor look like?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, capacitance

I've just finished the chapter about capacitors on my textbook, and I have a question. So, there are problems in my textbook where the capacitance of different arrangements of charged surfaces is asked to be calculated, and it made me wonder if there is an optimal design that maximizes the capacitance of such arrangement.

As far as I can think, two sheets of conductor extremely close to each other would be a *fair* guess. But I'm just not sure if it works that simple. I would appreciate your thoughts on this matter.